# Create a new wordpress post using Python (xmlrpc or wordpress_xmlrpc)

Tags: python, wordpress

I'm trying to automate some blog posting so that I can automatically post the contents of a text file onto a wordpress site I use for school. The site is wordpress version 4.1.1

So far I have tried using the [wordpress_xmlrpc method](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) and have been having some difficulties.

Here's an example of the code I've been trying to use:

```
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts

client = Client(...)
posts = client.call(posts.GetPosts())

page = WordPressPage()
page.title = 'About Me'
page.content = 'I am an aspiring WordPress and Python developer.'
page.post_status = 'publish'
page.id = client.call(posts.NewPost(page))

page.content = 'I am a WordPress and Python developer.'
client.call(posts.EditPost(page.id, page))
```

I don't particularly need anything complicated, I just want to get a simple python script working that creates a simple post on my school's blog.

Any help with why my examples aren't working, or any other examples that could work is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with `client.call(posts.getPosts())`...Watch the case! It should be: `client.call(posts.GetPosts())`, with a capital `G`.

The error clues you into this:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getPosts'

This would be a reminder to check the [methods of `posts`](https://python-wordpress-xmlrpc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/methods.html). A quick search will expose the simple typo.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that when I was making the question, but I did actually fix that later. Still having issues however, I'll edit the question to fix it now

Comment: You need to edit the question with your new error as well...It's still showing the old one, which would imply my answer is still valid